# url routing to root URL and forms authentication asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, routes, forms-authentication

I am facing an issue with URL routing in asp.net 3.5(not MVC),I am using FORMS authentication.the issue is that when I hit my website URL as [www.example.com](http://example.com) the default page is not displayed.as i am using forms authentication my login url and default url is different.so if some one hits the url it displays the login URL as http://www.example.com/login.aspx?returnurl=%2f where as it should show  www.example.com. I am not able to understand how to handle the issue.

but when i remove the following tags from the web.config it works fine.

```
    <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

I am not facing this issue for any other routes.i.e if someone hits www.example.com/abc/def it works fine.If someone can please help me in handling the returnURL issue. I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag you mentioned is for authorization

Normally you dont need these tags in web.config till you implement authroization.

So you are ok to remove this.

Comment: but we are using authroization as well